# How do I install Alientvault SIEM manually?

Tags: software-installation

AlienVault by defult is a .iso image. It installed on the core of Debian. I want to install it on Ubuntu 12.04. How can i do that?! Or is it possible or not?!
(AlienVault is a SIEM product, it is an open source monitoring security logs .., and use in Security Operations Center. Due to some reasons i need to installing it on Ubuntu. All the files of this product are in pool directory of its Debian .iso image.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not deserve the effort. OSSIM uses a highly modified Debian system and dozens of third-party applications, glued with several source code changes. Install and configure all these components in Ubuntu from scratch it would be a nice challenge but painful.

Why you need to install it on Ubuntu? It would be more easy to add to AlienVault these features.

Comment: Now it's configuration is by text!! Is it possible to add a GUI to it or not?!! In fact i'm new to linux!!

Comment: Yeah, you are right, it is not possible to installing all the components of the OSSIM. Thanks